# Coordinates of corners of camera view border

Tags: python, scripting

How to get coordinates of corners of camera border in camera view relative to the viewport area[image]?

After checking

```
import bpy
print('-----')
print()
print()
for a in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if a.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for s in a.spaces:
            print(s)
            for d in dir(s):
                print(d)
print('-----')
```

I have no idea how to find out where I can get this

Comment: Rather than using that unwieldy python script, you can explore the structure using the "Datablocks" mode of the Outliner. I'm looking around to see if I can find a way to actually get the coordinates :)

Comment: Yes, I know about Outliner, but Outliner is for datablocks, and what I wanna get is not store in datablocks at all. 100 % information =)

Comment: I'm not so sure it's possible to get it directly, you'd probably have to calculate it from the zoom and the camera's attributes...

Comment: Same thoughts, but it's too hard. Need to do a commit later.

Comment: It's something like what I wanted. Thank you, guys.<An_Ony_Moose> CoDEmanX: bpy.data.screens['Default'].areas[2].spaces[0].region_3d.perspective_matrix and bpy.data.screens['Default'].areas[2].spaces[0].region_3d.view_matrix? Maybe? (you may have to change the 2)

Comment: Now trying to get data from matrix with this http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

Comment: And this snippet from F2 Addon

Comment: world_pos = ob.matrix_world * vert.co.copy()
            screen_pos = view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d(region,
                region_3d, world_pos)

Comment: You've lost me, but if you're getting anywhere that's good :)

Comment: It should be possible to convert the NDC to screen coord using the projection matrix and W according to some 3d grapgics web posts. I'm unsure if `perspective_matrix` is the same as projection matrix however, and no clue from where to take W. Looking at the C code that draws the orange camera border, it appears to be quite complex to calculate. The easiest way would be to expose a new RNA method like `Camera.view_frame` for the border in C, to be called from python. Dunno how to deal with the parameters yet (call on cam ob, pass scene and view3d area, without an actual border drawn on screen?)

Comment: Before getting the coordinates I can check area.spaces[0].region3d.view_perspective == 'CAMERA'. It works cool =)

Comment: Could you do a commit to 2.70? No matter what - through camera or viewport data =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 things to consider here:

- The camera frame. *The camera frame is not as simple as you might expect since its effected by the field-of-view, aspect & x/y shift.*
- The 2D view pixel coords, *The user can pan & zoom the view, so this also has to be calculated.*

This script gets the camera bounds and prints the pixel boundaries.

```
import bpy

def view3d_find():
    # returns first 3d view, normally we get from context
    for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            v3d = area.spaces[0]
            rv3d = v3d.region_3d
            for region in area.regions:
                if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                    return region, rv3d
    return None, None

def view3d_camera_border(scene):
    obj = scene.camera
    cam = obj.data

    frame = cam.view_frame(scene=scene)

    # move from object-space into world-space 
    frame = [obj.matrix_world @ v for v in frame]

    # move into pixelspace
    from bpy_extras.view3d_utils import location_3d_to_region_2d
    region, rv3d = view3d_find()
    frame_px = [location_3d_to_region_2d(region, rv3d, v) for v in frame]
    return frame_px

frame_px = view3d_camera_border(bpy.context.scene)
print("Camera frame:", frame_px)
```

See API docs for the important functions used here:

- [bpy.types.Camera.view_frame](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.Camera.html#bpy.types.Camera.view_frame)
- [bpy_extras.view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy_extras.view3d_utils.html#bpy_extras.view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I actually needed! Your comment  "# move into object space" confused me. Maybe the comment should be like "moving into world space"? Because view_frame function gives the positions relatively to object space of the camera, and for getting pixelspace coordinates we must provide positions of the points in world space, don't we?

Comment: @sergey-krumas good point, done!

Comment: 2.8x API changes will require a small change:
frame = cam.view_frame(scene=scene)

Comment: Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 5):

Workaround example

Add a plane to the scene, to see the effect:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix
from bpy_extras import view3d_utils

mesh = bpy.data.objects['Plane'].data
camera = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
data = camera.data

frame = data.view_frame()
render = bpy.context.scene.render
ar = render.resolution_y / render.resolution_x

mesh.vertices[0].co = frame[0]
mesh.vertices[1].co = frame[1]
mesh.vertices[2].co = frame[3]
mesh.vertices[3].co = frame[2]

scale = Matrix.Scale(ar, 4, (0.0,1.0,0.0))
mat = camera.matrix_world

mesh.transform(mat*scale)
mesh.update()

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type=='VIEW_3D':
        break

space = area.spaces[0]
region = area.regions[4]

points_on_screen = [
    view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d(
        region,
        space.region_3d,
        v.co
        )
    for v in mesh.vertices
    ]

print(*points_on_screen, sep="\n")
```

You can apply the matrix transform directly to the vectors in `camera.view_frame` and use `location_3d_to_region_2d` to get the screen coordinates.

The plane is used for visualization.

BTW: To get the W-component you have to expand the vectors before multiplication

```
v = Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
v.to_4d()
# Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
```

`space_data.region_3d.perspective_matrix` seems to be already multiplied with the view matrix. You can reverse it like this:

```
perspective_matrix * view_matrix.inverted()
```

So

```
ndc = [None] * 4
for i, v in enumerate(camera.view_frame()):
    ndc[i] = perspective_matrix * matrix_world * scale * v.to_4d()
    ndc[i] /= ndc[i][3]
```

should give you the NDC-coordinates

Comment: Awesome pink vertex! This is exactly the calculation! I turned it into a modal draw op to visulize the result without a plane, fixed a problem with aspect ration > 1.0 and added a pink vertex in each corner =D It does not take Shift Y into account however, any idea how to solve this? http://www.pasteall.org/49117/python (*Run Script*, spacebar menu over 3D View, "modal", switch to camera view with *Numpad 0*!

Comment: Shift Y screws up the scaling because (0.0,0.0) is not the center anymore. You can fix this by a translation.

Comment: `center=sum(camera.view_frame(),Vector((0.0,0.0,0.0)))/4` Create a translation matrix `tmat=Matrix.Translation(Vector((0.0,-center[1],0.0))` And multiply it like this `tmat.inverted()*scale*tmat` You can simplify this by computing it by hand and set the entry in the scale matrix directly.

Comment: Great! Integrated the manual way into my script and accounted for aspect ration > 1.0 again: http://www.pasteall.org/49139/python Note that you need to be in Camera perspective already if you want to use the get points function standalone (or it won't return the correct locations).