# Normals not at centroids

Tags: normals

Why aren't the normals for the two inner rectangles located at the rectangle centroids as are the normals for the two outer rectangles? The four rectangles are supposed to be identical.

I'm running v2.80.44.

Thanks.

[image: Normals]

Comment: probably you have to flip the normals.

Comment: Thanks for replying. When I flip the normal, it's still off center, just on the other side.

Comment: the faces arent cutted? can you put an image in edit mode?

Comment: The image in my original post is in edit mode.

Comment: this is weird then, try to remove doubles, or better just change back to 2.79 because 2.80 its still in development and it has still bugs.

Comment: Suggest uploading a blend to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Answer (score 3):

Solved. Reduced problem to four rectangles and noted vertex count in status bar. The two inner rectangles each have an extra vertex.

This also shows that the location of the normal is not the centroid of the area, but the centroid of the vertices.

Blend uploaded to [image].

[image: Shows extra vertices]

Comment: I guess it _has_ to work this way, to allow non-planar faces to have something you can call a 'normal'..

Comment: @RobinBetts hmmm this may shed some light on this one (re comments) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91161/calculating-estimating-the-normal-at-any-location-on-a-face

Comment: @batFINGER phew! .. and I thought today was a relaxing day off  ... :D