# How to visualize transmissive ligth bounces with a line of Geometry?

Tags: python, scripting

**What I would like is something like this answer to a similar question:** https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/150400/126805

*.gif* **from that answer:**
[image]

---

But that it would go trough the object instead of bouncing of. So what I want is a transmissive bounce? Don't know if they are caled that.

I want this so I could see how a ligth ray go trough a camera lens, and since the only program I thought could help was *Blender* I asked this here, but if you have another option (a program or script) for this that would be helpful.

I also tried changing the material to glass, but that did not help.

---

- I am using *Blender 3.0*.
- And I have a little bit of *Python* programing knowledge but not with *bpy*.

---

**Comparison of what I want and what the person answered in the linked question:**
[image]

---

**Is it posible to modify the script to do this? Or create a new one that would work?**

Comment: See Snell’s Law as a topic, the Blender Manual page at https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/light_paths.html on the subject, and the rest of Cycles documentation.

Comment: Although this is technically about blender, blender light rays basically work like regular light rays (except that they are traced in reverse), so this is more of a physics question than a blender question.

Comment: luxcore should help, and try using volumes shader for cycles maybe

Comment: Edited the question because what I wanted to reference is the other questions answer and not the just the question.

Comment: And what I want is not a shading based answer but a one like in the links questions answer.

Comment: Of course it is possible to modify the script to do this. The script uses ray cast, fires a ray from a point in a direction into scene which if it hits an object returns a normal to the hit.  The bounce is a reflection vector calculated from ray direction `v` and normal. `n` which is `v = v.reflect(n)`. then repeat from hit location in bounce direction.. Instead if the ray hits a glass designated object refract the vector into the object, etc.