# How to get the precise mapping in python of a point in a texture to the point in which it has been mapped in an object?

Tags: python, uv, texture-coordinates

Let's say that I have a texture with a square, and I apply this texture to the surface of a object. I need to know that exact 3D coordinates of the borders of this square where they have been applied in the object.

My current solution is looking for the closest vertex in the object uv mapping to my desire square coordinates. Then I get the 3D coordinates of that vertex. However this is not an exact solution since I use the closest vertex. I could make it more precise by subdividing the object but I cant do that for other reasons.

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: To clarify, you want to map from UV -> xyz  .. where the mapping from xyz -> UV (eg project from view, cylindrical) is unknown?   Eg where on object surface is UV (0, 0)?

Comment: @batFINGER, exactly. I have some uv coordinates on the texture, and I want to get the coordinates where they have been mapped exactly.

Comment: Right now I search through the uv mappings of all vertices for the closest one to my desired uv coordinates, than i get the xyz coordinate of this closest vertex.

Comment: Important to note it may not be a 1:1 mapping (2d -> 3d) trivial example is blank UV,  every value is l (0, 0) mapping it to whole surface.  For a spherical projection maps top and bottom line of UV map to poles of sphere. Knowing its a spherical proj, we know the inverse. Without not sure .. this may be of some use https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91161/calculating-estimating-the-normal-at-any-location-on-a-face