# Extending Camera Faces

Tags: mesh, scripting, camera

I have a camera with a specific Field of View (FOV). I need to convert the camera's faces into planes then extend them to surround the camera view. The result might be something like a cone as shown in the lower part of the image. Scaling the existing camera won't be useful for me as the faces/sides won't be planes. I understand creating a cone and editing some values might give me the same thing I will get from extending the camera faces (calling face might not be technically correct though). However, we have to change the camera FOV very often thus cone solution might not be feasible for the long run. Is there any python script or solution to do that?

[image]

Comment: @susu I have made some edits as I have to have faces/sides converted into planes.

Comment: Hello :). Just out of curiosity - why do you need to do this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187233/bpy-how-do-you-find-the-corners-of-a-camera-frustum

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185446/camera-coverage-calculation-inside-a-room

Comment: @JachymMichal I need to extract part of an object that falls inside than camera view. I will do that using the Boolean modifier in Blender 2.76 as 2.8's boolean can't do that. It's a part of a Ph.D. research project (in the field of Ag. Engg.).