# How can I use Python to capture the whole mesh in the camera from an angle?

Tags: python, camera

How can I use Python to capture the whole mesh in the camera from an angle?

bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view_selected() will be a frontal angle.
I want to capture the whole mesh in the camera while maintaining the angle like
3D viewport's "." button, but bpy.ops.view3d.view_selected() doesn't seem to work from python

Comment: Do I understand your question: The camera is already in position, pointing along a line towards the selected mesh, and now you want to move it along that line to a point where the whole mesh is visible, preserving the angle?

Comment: Yes, sir. That's right. But it does not have to be strictly so.
What I want to do is render from an oblique view in Python to create a thumbnail of the mesh. The front view doesn't really show the shape.

Comment: I don't think there's a specific bpy op that does what you want, but there are questions here about calculating the [viewing frustum](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/187270/42221), determining if the bounding box of an object is in it, and simply moving the camera. You might find an answer among them.

Comment: Thank you! I will check that and try