Is there a (performant) way to raycast on points?
Importing a .ply file will be a Mesh with vertices for each points, but no edges or faces. To render this pointcloud, one has to create a geometry node setup like this:

Here is the problem/goal:
I built a raycasting script in python, which is able to shoot rays through each pixel of the scene camera. I want to get back information about which point is visible at a certain pixel. However, a point or vertex can never be hit (which makes perfect sense).
The obvious solution would be to use a instance on points node, however I am dealing with quite big point clouds, so performance will go to unusable levels if I do that (or Blender simply crashes)
We also already tried to simply render the ID information simply as attribute, but this leads to other issues (float32 precision for big index values), so I tried to go the ray-casting route.
The Mesh to Points node has the radius parameter, so there is some kind of geometry in there somewhere, I just cannot figure out how to access it for the ray-caster.
So the question is, if it is somehow possible to cast rays onto a pointcloud in blender?
Additional note:
One way I though about, was selecting points within the camera view frustum and casting rays from those point position to the camera position and check whether those hit the viewing plane. But depending on the camera position, this might lead to a huge amount of rays.

I don't think it is possible. Raycasting is based on triangles (quad and ngon by extension). As you said, you would never get a collision with points. Also, the radius from Mesh to Points is just the radius of the points generated, which is a intrinsic value of Points. No geometry there.

@Lutzi yes, unfortunately it seems like it...

I only have a basic understanding of it, but what you are describing make me think of raymarching. It may be another approach ? I can't help you more nor tell you if it's somewhat possible with Blender and Python.

Ray marching is similar, you would go along the ray in certain steps and read values at them. I try and build something not far from that. I am thinking about generating a bounding box with the "frustum" of a pixel and simply test which points are withing this bounding box. This might work with some performance optimization.

Rather than randomly casting rays from the camera I suggest you cast rays from the points. There are several methods that come in mind but you could take information from https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/187270/86891 Construct the view frustum planes, compute the dot product of each point with the normals of the 4 planes, if all of them are positive then the point is inside the view frustum (conversely if at least one is negative, point is outside of frustum). Might be crazily expensive to compute but you won't miss data and you might be able to optimize things by constructing a BVH tree.

Came here to say what @Gorgious mentioned at the end. I would check out the bvhtree module that comes with blender. I think this is the best bet.
